How can I define a Java meta annotation that specifies the @Target of annotations it's applied to?
How can I define a Java meta annotation that specifies the @Target of annotations it's applied to? In code it could look something like:
// The current target
@Target({ ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE })
// The target of the annotation this is applied to
@Target({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface MetaAnnotation {
}

@MetaAnnotation
// No @Target needed, targets ElementType.PARAMETER
public @interface RegularAnnotation {

}

But that's not possible since @Target can only be supplied once.

Java's @Target annotation cannot be used multiple times on the same annotation. However, you can achieve the desired behavior by defining a meta-annotation to specify the applicable targets for annotations it is applied to and processing these meta-annotations during compile-time or runtime.
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;
@Target(ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE)
public @interface MetaAnnotation {
    ElementType[] value(); // Specify the allowed targets
}





@MetaAnnotation({ ElementType.PARAMETER })
public @interface RegularAnnotation {
    // This annotation is implicitly targeted to ElementType.PARAMETER
}


How does this limit where @RegularAnnotation can be used? It has no @Target annotation which means it allows the annotation to be used anywhere.
